# PHP to update CSS

Tags: php, css, opencart

I need to update the css according to section_name. If section is **Featured** css would be `right:0` and if section_name is **Latest** the css would be `left:0` How can I inject a piece of php into css ?

```
<img src="square-009.jpg" style="width:300px; height:355px; position: fixed; z-index:9; right:0;" />
```

The section_name variable is already defined and it is working as

```
<?php echo $section['section_name']; ?>
```

Comment: Though that is certainly possible this is _not_ how css is meant to be used. Instead you define static css rules for _classes_ and apply those to your sections.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use classes:

```
.Featured {
  width:300px;
  height:355px;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:9;
  right:0;
}

.Latest {
  width:300px;
  height:355px;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:9;
  left:0;
}
```

And then just populate the class dynamically:

```
<img src="square-009.jpg" class="<?php echo $section['section_name']; ?>" />
```

Comment: Work like a charm. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Selim Happy to help! Please accept the answer so other users with the same question can benefit from it.